# How to produce a Calder mobile?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks, generative-art

Alexander Calder (1898 - 1976) was an American artist known for for his mobiles and his public sculptures.

Here are two examples of his mobiles which I want to approximately reproduce with `Mathematica`:

[image]

The second example has different colors:

[image]

We can use `BSplineCurve` to draw a Calder-like rounded shape:

```
gr = Graphics[BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2.5, 0.5}, {1, 0.5}, {0, 1}}, SplineClosed -> True]]
```

and this answer of kglr: [How to draw a colored curved shape](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220739/how-to-draw-a-colored-curved-shape) to fill it:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[gr, MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Darker @ Red}]
```

[image]

Maybe one could proceed with `TreePlot`, but with our rounded red shapes as `VertexShapeFunction`.

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 2, 7 -> 3, 8 -> 4, 9 -> 0},
 VertexShapeFunction -> "RoundedTriangle",
 VertexSize -> 0.2]
```

[image]

Or would it be easier to use `Graphics`- directives (slightly curved connected lines with randomized Calder-shapes)?

I don't know how to proceed and thank you in advance for any suggestions or, hopefully, a Calder-like solution.

Comment: So I suppose you also want these mobiles to be "physically" correct? Namely, when they are suspended, the forces and torques are in balance? :)

Comment: Nope - I'm more interested in an aesthetically appealing image.

Comment: What is the meaning of "mobile" here? Any synonyms?

Comment: @azerbajdzan From the Cambridge Dictionary: 
_"mobile: a decoration or work of art that has many parts that move freely in the air, for example hanging from threads"_

Comment: @flinty: Yes, also a kinetic sculpture as I found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_(sculpture).

Comment: I have been playing around with kirma's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/215771/72953) and getting random polygons with smooth edges. I haven't really figured out how to label tree vertices yet though, and it doesn't look perfect.

Comment: Something like `ClusteringTree[RandomReal[1, 10]]` could be a starting point. Maybe one can "extract" the tree-structure from there and "render" it as wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With minor modifications of `gr` in OP:

```
ClearAll[randomLeaf]

randomLeaf  := Module[{tip = {RandomReal[{2, 5}], RandomReal[{-1/2, 0}]}}, 
  Graphics[
   BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {0, 0},  {1, -1/2}, tip, tip,
      {RandomReal[{1, 3}], RandomReal[{0, 1/3}]}, {0, 1/2}}, 
    SplineClosed -> True]]]


SeedRandom[1];

Row @ Table[Show[randomLeaf, ImageSize -> 200], 5]
```

[image]

We can use `randomLeaf` as custom arrowhead in a custom `EdgeShapeFunction` as follows:

```
ClearAll[calderESF]

calderESF[leaflist_, sizes_: {.05,.2},curvature_ : {-.2, .2}] := 
 {Arrowheads[{{If[MemberQ[leaflist, #2[[2]]], 
     RandomReal[sizes], 0], 1.,
     Show @ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[randomLeaf, 
       MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> RandomColor[]}]}}], 
   GraphComputation`GraphElementData["CurvedEdge", 
     "Curvature" -> RandomReal[curvature]][##]} &
```

***Examples:***

```
branches = 
  Map[Reverse]@{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 2, 
    7 -> 3, 8 -> 4, 9 -> 0};

leaves = GraphComputation`SinkVertexList @ Graph @ branches;

SeedRandom[1];

Graph[branches, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> calderESF[leaves],
 VertexSize -> 0,
 VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 50}, {100, 10}}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];

branches2 = EdgeList@IndexGraph@RandomTree@20;

leaves2 = GraphComputation`SinkVertexList @ Graph @ branches2;

SeedRandom[444];

Graph[branches2, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> calderESF[leaves2], 
 VertexSize -> 0,
 VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
 GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 ImagePadding -> {{220, 150}, {200, 10}}]
```

[image]

Replace `"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` with `"RadialEmbedding"` and, `ImagePadding -> ...` with `ImagePadding -> 200` to get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This answer is quite lacking, and there's a lot of improvements to be made. Maybe someone can improve on this however.

Using kirma's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215762/rounding-an-irregular-polygon/215771#215771) (and modifying the parameters a little), we can get shapes (smoothed random polygons) that kind of look like Calder shapes.

We can then assign the VertexShapes to be these random smooth polygons:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
{minPolySides, maxPolySides} = {3, 6};
mobileStructure = {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 2, 
   7 -> 3, 8 -> 4, 9 -> 0};
numberofThings = 10;

randomPolys = 
  Table[With[{coords = 
      Append[#, #[[1]]] &@
       RandomPolygon[{"Convex", 
          RandomInteger[{minPolySides, maxPolySides}]}][[1]]}, 
    With[{ip = 
       Interpolation[
        Transpose@{Rescale@
           Accumulate@
            Prepend[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[coords, 2, 1], 0],
           coords}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]}, 
     Graphics[{FaceForm@Red, 
       Polygon@Table[
         Mean@Table[ip[Mod[t + t0, 1]], {t0, 0, 0.3, .01}], {t, 0, 
          1., .01}]}]]], numberofThings];

vs = Thread[Range[0, numberofThings - 1] -> randomPolys];
TreePlot[mobileStructure,
 VertexShape -> vs, VertexSize -> 0.5, EdgeStyle -> Thick, 
 BaseStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is still missing some critical properties of your two examples though:

1. It looks like in your examples of Calder's mobiles, some tree vertices do not have a "shape" on them, and are instead just branching points for multiple shapes to hang off of.
2. The shapes are really not perfect still, I think I may have made them too smooth

Comment: +1 - it's much more than just a promising start :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple example that you can play with.

```
vf[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := 
 Module[{rr = RandomReal[{-1/4, 0}]}, 
  BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[
   BSplineCurve[{xc, yc} + RotationMatrix[rr*\[Pi]] . # & /@ {{0, 
       0}, {RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
       RandomReal[{-1, 0}]}, {RandomReal[{1, 2}], 
       RandomReal[{-1, 0}]}, {RandomReal[{1, 2}], 
       RandomReal[{1, 0}]}, {RandomReal[{0.5, 1}], 
       RandomReal[{1, 0}]}, {0, 0}}], 
   MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> ColorData[97, RandomInteger[15]]}]]

ef[pts_List, e_] := 
 BSplineCurve[{pts[[1]], Mean[pts] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2], pts[[2]]}]

Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3}, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 2}, {0, 4}},
  VertexShapeFunction -> 1 | 2 | 3 -> vf, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (# -> ef & /@ {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3})]
```

[image]

[image]